# Make UIBarButtonItem open a link in safari?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, openurl

Hello I'm all new to the iPhone development thingy, so I would appreciate some help here.
I would like my UIBarButton to close the app and then open up a link in safari.

`in the .h file`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MoviesViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *rightButton_;


}

- (void) goSafari;


@end
```

`in the .m file`

```
    #import "MoviesViewController.h"


@implementation MoviesViewController


/*
 // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    

    rightButton_ = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goSafari)]autorelease];


}

- (void) goSafari {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];

}


// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong here with the code. And you're setting up target/action in code so its not a problem with an IB connection either.

Comment: when i click the button nothing happends...

Comment: it gives me 2 warnings: "Incomplete implementation of class 'FirstViewController'" and "Method definition for '-goSafari' not found"

Comment: Can you post the entire interface and implementation? Also make sure the outlet is connected in interface builder.

Answer (score 2):

Your "gosafari" method implementation is incorrectly titled - should be "goSafari" to match the specified selector and method prototype.

Comment: put a breakpoint in goSafari -- does it get called?  Did your "incomplete implementation of class" warning go away?

Comment: also, from your code it's not clear that "rightButton_" is being used.  It looks like you have another button "donateButton_" which may be set up in you XIB via Interface Builder.  If that's the case, double check the button event handler is properly connected in Interface Builder.

Comment: I think it's a pretty good chance that the rightButton_ in your code is not the button you're pressing.  My bet is you have a button defined in your Interface Builder file (.xib) and it's not attached to rightButton_.  Try changing the title of the button from "Title" to something else, and see if it changes when you run the app.  If not, then you need to straighten out which button is which, and how they're all connected.

Comment: as I said before i'm very new to objC so i will need a little more help than that